# Retyping alias column in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, column-alias

I am trying to convert some data from old tables to a new structure, where I need to convert a single key ID to composite one, amd it is giving me some trouble:

### My table (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE `tmplt_spoergsmaal` (
  `SpID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lbnr` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `SpTekst` text,
  `SpTitel` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fk_Naeste_Sp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `kontrol` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `kontrol_kilde` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  FOREIGN KEY (kontrol_kilde) 
    REFERENCES tmplt_spoergsmaal(SpID)
    ON DELETE ignore
)
```

### Sample data:

*Note that SPID is sequential*

```
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|  SpID  |  lbnr  |  SpTekst  |  SpTitel  |   kontrol  |  kontrol_kilde  | 
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|  9000  |  100   | blablabla | title1    |      0     |     null        |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|  9001  |  101   | blablabla | title2    |      0     |     null        |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|  9002  |  102   | blablabla | title3    |      0     |     null        |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|  9003  |  103   | blablabla | title4    |      1     |       9000      |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
|  9004  |  104   | blablabla | title5    |      1     |       9001      |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-----------------+
```

I am redesigning the database, and using the `lbnr` column instead of the `kontrol_kilde` column. My preliminary query is this:

```
SELECT spid, lbnr, kontrol, kontrol_kilde, (lbnr- (spid - kontrol_kilde)* kontrol)* kontrol AS k
FROM tmplt_spoergsmaal;
```

This solves my issue, but an issue cropped up at one point (because of a flip of the subtraction (`spid - kontrol_kilde` had become `kontrol_kilde - spid`) which made part of the equation negative. Since the column is unsigned,this caused an error:

> `Error Code: 1690. BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in`

### My question:

Can I "cast" the columns in the alias column `k` so that it is an `int` instead of `unsigned int` ?

Comment: What's a relative id? This just sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: Essentially I'm "just" switching it from using the spid column to the lbnr column... I have not provided the complete code, just an [mcve]

Comment: I removed the wording...

Comment: It's not the wording, but the plan, that I think is at fault

Comment: this is a small part of a bigger picture, and not the part I am asking about... the wording was flawed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can `cast()` as `signed`:

```
SELECT spid, lbnr, kontrol, kontrol_kilde,
       cast(lbnr - (spid - kontrol_kilde) * kontrol)* kontrol as signed) AS k
FROM tmplt_spoergsmaal;
```